# Extract metadata from pic without uploading the whole pic

Tags: image, image-processing, metadata

I was trying to figure it out, if it will be possible to extract the metadata from the pics, without having to download/upload the whole pic file.

I was looking at through internet several libraries to do this, but for what I have found until now all of them required of opening the whole file.

I was looking for the formats that are [standards nowadays](https://www.photometadata.org/node/37/) and I found out that only XMP allows obtaining this info separated from the file itself.

There is a way that I could obtain the GPS coordinates with only a part of the file?

I think this will be good from the point of view of privacy and performance.

Regards, Roberto

Comment: Can I know why someone has downpost this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download part of file with `curl` by using the `-r` parameter. So, let's take the first 16kB of a file and pass that to `jhead` to get the EXIF/GPS data:

```
curl -r 0-16000 "http://thesetchells.com/a.jpg" | jhead /dev/stdin
```

**Sample Output**

```
File name    : /dev/stdin
File size    : 0 bytes
File date    : 2018:01:09 13:39:45
Camera make  : Apple
Camera model : iPhone 4
Date/Time    : 2013:03:09 08:59:50
Resolution   : 2592 x 1936
Flash used   : No
Focal length :  3.8mm  (35mm equivalent: 35mm)
Exposure time: 0.0011 s  (1/914)
Aperture     : f/2.8
ISO equiv.   : 80
Whitebalance : Auto
Metering Mode: pattern
Exposure     : program (auto)
GPS Latitude : N 20d 50.66m  0s
GPS Longitude: E 107d  5.46m  0s
GPS Altitude :  1.13m
JPEG Quality : 96
```

The amount you need will vary, and I found I needed a minimum of around 14kB with this particular image. The full image is actually 2,219,100 bytes.

Comment: Thanks it was what I was looking for